# Meaning of 'kws' from seaborn

Tags: python, seaborn

What does it mean 'kws' when using 'line_kws' from seaborn?
I know its function is to change the line color of regplot, but..the meaning.
Is it an acronym of some words?
I'm curious about it..

I googled and also looked into the documentation, but couldn't find what that means.

Comment: "keywords".  Those hold additional keyword for the lines.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the documentation:

> *{scatter,line}_kwsdictionaries*
>
> Additional keyword arguments to pass to plt.scatter and plt.plot

Given the description it is likely to mean ***k***ey***w***ord***s***.